# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file

Tags: magento-1.9

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home/*****/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/*****/template/anybooking/booking/list.phtml on line 261
```

Here's the file that causing the issue

```
<?php 
/**
 * Apptha
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the EULA
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://www.apptha.com/LICENSE.txt
 *
 * ==============================================================
 *                 MAGENTO EDITION USAGE NOTICE
 * ==============================================================
 * This package designed for Magento COMMUNITY edition
 * Apptha does not guarantee correct work of this extension
 * on any other Magento edition except Magento COMMUNITY edition.
 * Apptha does not provide extension support in case of
 * incorrect edition usage.
 * ==============================================================
 *
 * @category    Apptha
 * @package     Apptha_Anybooking
 * @version     0.1.7
 * @author      Apptha Team <developers@contus.in>
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2014 Apptha. (http://www.apptha.com)
 * @license     http://www.apptha.com/LICENSE.txt
 *
 */
?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&amp;sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            //center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8688, 151.2195),
            zoom: 13,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
        mapOptions);

        var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

        autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
        // Autocomplete.
        function setupClickListener(id, types) {
            var radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(radioButton, 'click', function() {
                autocomplete.setTypes(types);
            });
        }

    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('home_page_sliders')->toHtml() ?>

<?php
$count = 1;
$threeDiv = 1;
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$baseurl = Mage::getBaseUrl('skin');
$bookingTimeData = $bookingTimeId = Mage::helper('anybooking')->getBookingTimeLabelByOptionId();

$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
$wishList = Mage::getSingleton('wishlist/wishlist')->loadByCustomer($customer);
$wishListItemCollection = $wishList->getItemCollection();

$arrProductIds = array();

if (count($wishListItemCollection)) {
    foreach ($wishListItemCollection as $item) {
        $product = $item->getProduct();
        $arrProductIds[] = $product->getId();
    }
}

$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('anybooking/booking')->getbookingcollection()
                ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => 1))
                ->addAttributeToFilter('bookingapproved',array('eq' => 1)) 
                ->setPageSize(10)->setOrder('created_at', 'desc')->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$currencySymbol = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol();
if(count($_productCollection)!= 0){

?>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="roomshomepage">
    <div id="room" class="clearfix">
        <div id="left_columnhomepage">
            <div id="main_content" class="box">
                <div class="tabhomepage">

                    <ul id="main_content_sub_navhomepage" class="rooms_sub_navhomepage clearfix">
                        <li id="menuwhatnew" class="main_link selected">
                            <a href="#whatnew" onclick="showTabs('whatsnew','menuwhatnew')"><?php echo $this->__("What's New"); ?></a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menuRated" class="main_link">
                            <a href="#mostrated" onclick="showTabs('rated_div','menuRated')"><?php echo $this->__('Most Rated'); ?></a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menuPopular" class="main_link">
                            <a href="#mostrated" onclick="showTabs('popular_div','menuPopular')"><?php echo $this->__('Most Popular'); ?></a>
                        </li>                            

                    </ul>
                    <div id="whatsnew" class="main_content" style="display: block; ">
                        <ul id="homepage_badges" class="rounded tab-section" style="display: block;<?php if(count($_productCollection)== 0 ) echo 'text-align: center;' ?> ">
                            <?php                 
                           if(count($_productCollection)!= 0 ){
                            $count = 1;
                            foreach ($_productCollection as $_product):
                                if ($count <= 4):
                                    ?>

                            <?php
                                $mainimage=$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')
                                ->constrainOnly(TRUE)
                                ->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)
                                ->keepFrame(FALSE)
                                ->resize(200,null)
                            ?>

                                    <li class="rounded" <?php if($count == 4) { echo 'style=" margin-right:0;" ' ;}?>>
                                        <a class="ss_name" href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl() . $_product->getUrlPath(); ?>">
                                            <img src="<?php
                            if ($_product->getImage() != 'no_selection') {
                                echo $mainimage;
                            } else { 
                                echo $_product->getImageUrl();
                            }
                                    ?>" width="195" height="130" alt="<?php echo Mage::helper('anybooking/booking')->getBookingName($_product->getName()); ?>" >
                                        </a>
                                        <div class="box-shadow">
                                             <a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl() . $_product->getUrlPath(); ?>" style="text-decoration: none;">
                                            <?php echo Mage::helper('anybooking/booking')->getBookingName($_product->getName()); ?>
                                             </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <?php
                                endif;
                                $count++;
                            endforeach;
                           }else{ ?>
                             <li class="homepage_no_records_found"><span><?php echo $this->__('No Records!') ?></span></li>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!-- most rated -->
                         <?php $rateCollection = Mage::getModel('anybooking/booking')->getRatedBooking();?>
                    <div id="rated_div" class="main_content" style="display: none;">
                        <ul id="rated_badges" class="rounded tab-section" style="display: block; <?php if(count($rateCollection)== 0 ) echo "text-align: center;" ?>">
                            <?php                         
                             if(count($rateCollection)!= 0 ){
                              $countRate = 1;                              
                              for ($s = 0; $s < count($rateCollection); $s++) {
                              $rateProduct = $model->load($rateCollection[$s]["entity_id"]);
                                ?>
                             <?php                

                                $rateimage=$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($rateProduct, 'image')
                                ->constrainOnly(TRUE)
                                ->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)
                                ->keepFrame(FALSE)
                                ->resize(200,null) 
                            ?>
                                <li class="rounded" <?php if($countRate == 4) { echo 'style=" margin-right:0;" ' ;}?>>
                                    <a class="ss_name" href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl() . $rateProduct->getUrlPath(); ?>">
                                        <img alt=" <?php  echo Mage::helper('anybooking/booking')->getBookingName($rateProduct->getName()); ?>" src="<?php
                            if ($rateProduct->getImage() != 'no_selection') {
                                echo $rateimage;
                            } else {
                                echo $rateProduct->getImageUrl();
                            }
                            ?>" width="195" height="130" >
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="box-shadow">
                                         <a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl() . $rateProduct->getUrlPath(); ?>" style="text-decoration: none;">
                                        <?php echo Mage::helper('anybooking/booking')->getBookingName($rateProduct->getName()); ?>
                                         </a>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            <?php 
                              $countRate++;
                                }
                             }else{ ?>
                             <li class="homepage_no_records_found"><span><?php echo $this->__('No Records!') ?></span></li>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!-- most rated ends -->
                    <!-- most popular -->
                     <?php
                    $rateCollection = Mage::getModel('anybooking/booking')->getPopularBooking();
                    ?>
                    <div id="popular_div" class="main_content" style="display: none;">
                        <ul id="popular_badges" class="rounded tab-section" style="display: block; <?php if(count($rateCollection)== 0 ) echo "text-align: center;" ?>">
                            <?php          

                         if(count($rateCollection)!= 0 ){

                           $countPopular = 1;
                            for ($s = 0; $s < count($rateCollection); $s++) {
                                $popularCollection = $model->load($rateCollection[$s]["entity_id"]);                                     

                                $popularImage=$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($popularCollection, 'image')
                                ->constrainOnly(TRUE)
                                ->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)
                                ->keepFrame(FALSE)
                                ->resize(200,null) 
                            ?>

                                <li class="rounded" <?php if($countPopular == 4) { echo 'style=" margin-right:0;" ' ;}?>>
                                    <a class="ss_name" href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl() . $popularCollection->getUrlPath(); ?>">
                                        <img alt="<?php echo Mage::helper('anybooking/booking')->getBookingName($popularCollection->getName()); ?>" src="<?php
                            if ($popularCollection->getImage() != "no_selection") {
                                echo $popularImage;
                            } else {
                                echo $popularCollection->getImageUrl();
                            }
                            ?>" width="195" height="130"  >
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="box-shadow">
                                        <a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl() . $popularCollection->getUrlPath(); ?>" style="text-decoration: none;">
                                        <?php echo Mage::helper('anybooking/booking')->getBookingName($popularCollection->getName()); ?>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <?php
                               $countPopular++;
                             }
                             }else{ ?>
                             <li class="homepage_no_records_found"><span><?php echo $this->__('No Records!') ?></span></li>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!-- most popular -->


                </div>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




<script type="text/javascript">
    var $slide = jQuery.noConflict();
    function showTabs(id,menuName){
        $slide(".main_content").hide();
        $slide(".main_link").removeClass("selected");
        $slide("#"+menuName).addClass("selected");
        $slide("#"+id).show();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
/**
* Apptha
*
* NOTICE OF LICENSE
*
* This source file is subject to the EULA
* that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
* It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
* http://www.apptha.com/LICENSE.txt
*
* ==============================================================
                *                 MAGENTO EDITION USAGE NOTICE
* ==============================================================
* This package designed for Magento COMMUNITY edition
* Apptha does not guarantee correct work of this extension
* on any other Magento edition except Magento COMMUNITY edition.
* Apptha does not provide extension support in case of
* incorrect edition usage.
* ==============================================================
*
    * @category    Apptha
    * @package     Apptha_Anybooking
    * @version     0.1.7
    * @author      Apptha Team <developers@contus.in>
* @copyright   Copyright (c) 2014 Apptha. (http://www.apptha.com)
    * @license     http://www.apptha.com/LICENSE.txt
*
*/
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&amp;sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            //center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8688, 151.2195),
            zoom: 13,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
        mapOptions);
        var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
        autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
        // Autocomplete.
        function setupClickListener(id, types) {
            var radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(radioButton, 'click', function() {
                autocomplete.setTypes(types);
            });
        }
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
<?php
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('home_page_sliders')->toHtml() ?>
<?php
$count = 1;
$threeDiv = 1;
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$baseurl = Mage::getBaseUrl('skin');
$bookingTimeData = $bookingTimeId = Mage::helper('anybooking')->getBookingTimeLabelByOptionId();
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
$wishList = Mage::getSingleton('wishlist/wishlist')->loadByCustomer($customer);
$wishListItemCollection = $wishList->getItemCollection();
$arrProductIds = array();
if (count($wishListItemCollection)) {
    foreach ($wishListItemCollection as $item) {
        $product = $item->getProduct();
        $arrProductIds[] = $product->getId();
    }
}
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('anybooking/booking')->getbookingcollection()->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => 1))->addAttributeToFilter('bookingapproved', array('eq' => 1))->setPageSize(10)->setOrder('created_at', 'desc')->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$currencySymbol = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol();
if (count($_productCollection) != 0) {
?>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="roomshomepage">
    <div id="room" class="clearfix">
        <div id="left_columnhomepage">
            <div id="main_content" class="box">
                <div class="tabhomepage">
                    <ul id="main_content_sub_navhomepage" class="rooms_sub_navhomepage clearfix">
                        <li id="menuwhatnew" class="main_link selected">
                            <a href="#whatnew" onclick="showTabs('whatsnew','menuwhatnew')"><?php
                            echo $this->__("What's New"); ?></a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menuRated" class="main_link">
                            <a href="#mostrated" onclick="showTabs('rated_div','menuRated')"><?php
                            echo $this->__('Most Rated'); ?></a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menuPopular" class="main_link">
                            <a href="#mostrated" onclick="showTabs('popular_div','menuPopular')"><?php
                            echo $this->__('Most Popular'); ?></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div id="whatsnew" class="main_content" style="display: block; ">
                        <ul id="homepage_badges" class="rounded tab-section" style="display: block;<?php
                            if (count($_productCollection) == 0) echo 'text-align: center;' ?> ">
                            <?php
                                if (count($_productCollection) != 0) {
                                    $count = 1;
                                    foreach ($_productCollection as $_product):
                                        if ($count <= 4):
                            ?>
                            <?php
                                            $mainimage = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->constrainOnly(TRUE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(200, null)
                            ?>
                            <li class="rounded" <?php
                                                if ($count == 4) {
                                                    echo 'style=" margin-right:0;" ';
                                } ?>>
                                <a class="ss_name" href="<?php
                                echo Mage::getBaseUrl() . $_product->getUrlPath(); ?>">
                                <img src="<?php
                                                if ($_product->getImage() != 'no_selection') {
                                                    echo $mainimage;
                                                }
                                                else {
                                                    echo $_product->getImageUrl();
                                                }
                                ?>" width="195" height="130" alt="<?php
                                echo Mage::helper('anybooking/booking')->getBookingName($_product->getName()); ?>" >
                                </a>
                                <div class="box-shadow">
                                    <a href="<?php
                                    echo Mage::getBaseUrl() . $_product->getUrlPath(); ?>" style="text-decoration: none;">
                                    <?php
                                    echo Mage::helper('anybooking/booking')->getBookingName($_product->getName()); ?>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <?php
                                        endif;
                                        $count++;
                                    endforeach;
                                }
                            else { ?>
                            <li class="homepage_no_records_found"><span><?php
                            echo $this->__('No Records!') ?></span></li>
                            <?php
                            } ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!-- most rated -->
                    <?php
                    $rateCollection = Mage::getModel('anybooking/booking')->getRatedBooking(); ?>
                    <div id="rated_div" class="main_content" style="display: none;">
                        <ul id="rated_badges" class="rounded tab-section" style="display: block; <?php
                            if (count($rateCollection) == 0) echo "text-align: center;" ?>">
                            <?php
                                if (count($rateCollection) != 0) {
                                    $countRate = 1;
                                    for ($s = 0; $s < count($rateCollection); $s++) {
                                        $rateProduct = $model->load($rateCollection[$s]["entity_id"]);
                            ?>
                            <?php

                                        $rateimage = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($rateProduct, 'image')->constrainOnly(TRUE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(200, null)
                            ?>
                            <li class="rounded" <?php
                                            if ($countRate == 4) {
                                                echo 'style=" margin-right:0;" ';
                                } ?>>
                                <a class="ss_name" href="<?php
                                echo Mage::getBaseUrl() . $rateProduct->getUrlPath(); ?>">
                                <img alt=" <?php
                                echo Mage::helper('anybooking/booking')->getBookingName($rateProduct->getName()); ?>" src="<?php
                                if ($rateProduct->getImage() != 'no_selection') {
                                echo $rateimage;
                                }
                                else {
                                echo $rateProduct->getImageUrl();
                                }
                                ?>" width="195" height="130" >
                                </a>
                                <div class="box-shadow">
                                    <a href="<?php
                                    echo Mage::getBaseUrl() . $rateProduct->getUrlPath(); ?>" style="text-decoration: none;">
                                    <?php
                                    echo Mage::helper('anybooking/booking')->getBookingName($rateProduct->getName()); ?>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <?php
                                        $countRate++;
                                    }
                                }
                            else { ?>
                            <li class="homepage_no_records_found"><span><?php
                            echo $this->__('No Records!') ?></span></li>
                            <?php
                            } ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!-- most rated ends -->
                    <!-- most popular -->
                    <?php
                        $rateCollection = Mage::getModel('anybooking/booking')->getPopularBooking();
                    ?>
                    <div id="popular_div" class="main_content" style="display: none;">
                        <ul id="popular_badges" class="rounded tab-section" style="display: block; <?php
                            if (count($rateCollection) == 0) echo "text-align: center;" ?>">
                            <?php

                                if (count($rateCollection) != 0) {

                                    $countPopular = 1;
                                    for ($s = 0; $s < count($rateCollection); $s++) {
                                        $popularCollection = $model->load($rateCollection[$s]["entity_id"]);

                                        $popularImage = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($popularCollection, 'image')->constrainOnly(TRUE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(200, null)
                            ?>
                            <li class="rounded" <?php
                                            if ($countPopular == 4) {
                                                echo 'style=" margin-right:0;" ';
                                } ?> >
                                <a class="ss_name" href="<?php
                                echo Mage::getBaseUrl() . $popularCollection->getUrlPath(); ?>">
                                <img alt="<?php
                                echo Mage::helper('anybooking/booking')->getBookingName($popularCollection->getName()); ?>" src="<?php
                                if ($popularCollection->getImage() != "no_selection") {
                                echo $popularImage;
                                }
                                else {
                                echo $popularCollection->getImageUrl();
                                }
                                ?>" width="195" height="130"  >
                                </a>
                                <div class="box-shadow">
                                    <a href="<?php
                                    echo Mage::getBaseUrl() . $popularCollection->getUrlPath(); ?>" style="text-decoration: none;">
                                    <?php
                                    echo Mage::helper('anybooking/booking')->getBookingName($popularCollection->getName()); ?>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <?php
                                        $countPopular++;
                                    }
                                }
                            else { ?>
                            <li class="homepage_no_records_found"><span><?php
                            echo $this->__('No Records!') ?></span></li>
                            <?php
                            } ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!-- most popular -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php } ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var $slide = jQuery.noConflict();
    function showTabs(id,menuName){
        $slide(".main_content").hide();
        $slide(".main_link").removeClass("selected");
        $slide("#"+menuName).addClass("selected");
        $slide("#"+id).show();
    }
</script>
```

This is some pretty bad code all the way around, sorry.

1) Don't use `count($collection)`, it's bad practice.
2) DO NOT do model `->load()` within a loop, this is also bad practice.

Both can result in very poor performing code.

I've already fixed the syntax error and cleaned up the formatting of the code, and fixed the count of collection.  Replacing the loads in the loop i'll leave up to you.  Also, stick with one syntax of brackets or not, there is a coding standard to help.

**References:**

- Conquer the 5 Most Common Magento Coding Issues to Optimize Your Site for Performance: http://info2.magento.com/rs/magentoenterprise/images/Conquer_the_5_Most_Common_Magento_Coding_Issues_to_Optimize_Your_Site_for_Performance.pdf
- Coding Standards to use with PHPCS: https://github.com/magento-ecg/coding-standard

Answer (score 2):

Closing brace

> }

is missing for

> (if(count($_productCollection)!= 0){

just add below line at end of your script

```
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Closing brace `}` for `if(count($_productCollection)!= 0){` is missing.
Add closing brace `}` at your required place.